# Java EE 7 JSF Facelet h:commandButton action redirect to page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

Hi I have an Java EE 7 Application in NetBeans  8.0.2 running on Glassfish 4.01

I use `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` as a controller `UserController.java`

I have an `index.xhtml` Facelet and an `signup.xhtml` Facelet

In the `index.xhtml` Facelet I have

```
<h:commandButton value="Sign Up" action="#{userController.signUp()}"></h:commandButton>
```

which calls the function `public String signUp() {` in the `UserController.java`

In this function I return `return Pages.SIGN_UP_PAGE;` which renders the Face let `signup.xhtml` there I have a Form to fill in your user data such as user Name email and password.

The first thing is that when I `return Pages.SIGN_UP_PAGE;` the page `signup.xhtml` gets rendered but in the URL still stands `.../faces/index.xhtml`

In `signup.xhtml` I have the

```
<h:commandButton value="Create User" action="#{userController.createNewUser()}"></h:commandButton>
```

Then in the `public String createNewUser()` function I return `return Pages.USER_ACTION_OVERVIEW;` which renders the page `overview.xhtml` but then with the URL
`.../faces/signup.xhtml`

which leads to the bigger problem that when I refresh now the page ( the overview page which shows me the data of the new signedUp user ) I send a POST request again to signUp() the same user with the same POST Parameters.

What I need is that if i render the page, that the right URL is displayed ( the on of the page which is rendered ) and that if I refresh that page that not again the old POST request gets send.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one. I think it is answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The JSF perforns a POST based request, that is why your url does not change. The solution is to add `faces-redirect` parameter to your query sttring like this

```
public String signUp () {
      //some processing here
      return Pages.SIGNUP_PAGE + "?faces-redirect=true";
 }
```

This will force a GET redirect to the sign up page after the POST request is completed. As a result,  your browser's address bar will show the address of the current page, i. e. the sign up page